# js регулярное выражение цифры от 6 до 10 знаков

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

мне нужна регулярка, которая будет разрешать: запятые, пробелы и цифры, я написал такую

```
/^[0-9,\s]*$/i;
```

но суть в том, что цифры должны быть от 6 до 10 знаков, то есть
000323,34345345, 1234567890, - это допустимое значение в поле, здесь есть запятые, пробелы и цифры,
45,4,1234567891011 - это уже не норм, потому что цифры, а точнее числа каждое отделенное запятой меньше 6 символов и больше 10 символов в длину, подскажите что нужно добавить в regexp, чтобы это поправить

Comment: где-то нужно добавить ``{6,10}``

Comment: если так /^[0-9,\s]{6,}/i; то идет валидация на то что не меньше 6 НО что очень важно, нужно чтобы валидация была для каждого отдельного числа 000323,34345345, здесь оба числа допустимые, а с этим правилом /^[0-9,\s]{6,}/i работает 6666666,44,1 - это тоже будет ок, а это не то что нужно, и вот так /^[0-9,\s]{6,10}/i не валидирует на макс число 10

Comment: потому что {6,10} должно относиться к цифрам, а не ко всей группе. Вместо 0-9 можно использовать /d, тогда проще

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Q1eIi1/1 - удобный сервис для тестирования ваших регулярных выражений, так же есть описание метасимволов, примеров конструкций групп. По ссылке доступен черновик для вашей задачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//        группы от 6 до 10 цифр
//             -----------
    /^([,\s]*\b[0-9]{6,10}\b[,\s]*)*$/
//           --           --
//  границы слов запрещают двум группам сливаться вместе
```

Comment: в js вроде не работает граница слова, `/т\b/.test('привет привет')`

Comment: Она работает для цифр, запятых и разнообразных пробелов. Других символов в строке не должно быть.

Comment: спасибо - то что нужно!

Comment: `,,,,,,, ,,, ,,,,, ,,123456,,,,,,,, ,, , , ,, , ` является валидной строкой для вашего регулярного выражения, так же не ясен параметр `i` ведь у цифр регистр написания

Comment: Кстати, пустая строка так же будет валидной

Comment: @ipatev_nn, параметр `i` убрал. Спасибо! Пустая строка в вопросе не запрещена, каша из запятых и пробелов тоже. Требования предъявлялись только к группам цифр.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
^(?:[\s,]*(?<!\d)\d{6,10}(?!\d))+[\s,]*$
```

Разрешаем 1+ групп цифр от 6 до 10 цифр `\d{6,10}`, за пределами этих групп разрешаем 0+ пробельных символов и запятых. Каждая цифровая группа ограничена НЕ-цифрой слева и справа (негативные просмотры назад `(?<!\d)` и вперед `(?!\d)`). Поскольку оцениваем весь текст целиком, то зона действия выражения - от начала `^` до конца `$` строки

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/pdB4EL/1)

Comment: Строка `,,,,,124568,,,,,,,,444444,,,,,,` является валидной для вашего регулярного выражения